# VS Code autocomplete for ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, visual-studio-code

I would like to get suggestions/autocomplete as I am typing methods and functions in VS Code for arcpy. Currently, IntelliSense would suggest only functions or methods that I have been using within the file, but would not some that I haven't.

I am using Python and Kite extensions. I have also cloned the Python environment in Pro and I am using that as a Python environment in VS Code.

I have tried to play a little bit with editor.quickSuggestions but haven't really done much.

Comment: Does VS Code recognise the correct arcgis python environment?  What happens when you press Ctrl+Space after typing `arcpy.` ?  Sometimes I have to type that with ctrl+space a couple times and give it a few seconds before the Intellisense works the first time, but then it's there for the entire session (have to do it again the next session)

Comment: Thank you for answer Midavalo, I have tried with ctrl+space but I would again get the same suggestions(only the ones that I have used in my code already). What I am looking for is to get suggestions similarly as in Python console within Pro. :( And yes, I think VS Code recognizes the environment, as I have no problem executing the program with Code.

Comment: Have you created a venv in vs code for arcpy?  Having it run could just be because python is in the windows PATH environment.

Comment: Well, besides selecting an interpreter in VS Code I haven't done something else. So currently I see in the left bottom of Code - Python 3.6.7. 64-bit('arcgis-py3-clone': conda). And the path is pointing to the environment ArcGIS Pro have created.

Comment: I think that venv was the wrong term in my comment above, but I have done a quick test and added an answer below with what works for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I had to do to get IntelliSense working with my arcpy project in VS Code:

1. In my project folder I created a new folder called `.vscode`

   [image]
2. In this folder I created a file called `settings.json`, and added the following to the json file:

   ```
   {
       "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3\\python.exe"
   }
   ```

   This is the path to my arcpy python install location - if yours is in a different location then specify that path instead.
3. Now when I open that project folder, I can type `arcpy.` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> two or three times and it'll pop up a message "Loading"

   [image]

   I had to wait several seconds (it wasn't a quick load), then the IntelliSense works.

   [image]

I did find I had to do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> step and wait for the load every time I opened the project, but while it was open the IntelliSense works fine after initial load

Comment: Thank you so much! This exact same approach hasn't worked for me but I have added your line of code with my python environment path under File -> Preferences -> Settings. Then go for Text Editor -> Suggestions -> Quick Suggestions 'Edit in settings.json'. However, I think that my approach will set every project to Python environment but there should be no problem to override this change on the 'select interpreter' option. I just wanted to write in case someone needs my approach. Thank you Midavalo

Comment: @Kumbra Feel free to [edit] my answer with the extra steps that made yours work, or add your own answer

Answer (score 4):

With the help of Midavalo answer, I figured out how to set up autocomplete for my VS Code. 
In VS Code just go under File -> Preferences -> Settings and then within Settings go for Text Editor -> Suggestions -> Quick Suggestions and open settings.json(Edit in settings.json). Over there add the same line of code that Midavalo posted

```
{
"python.pythonPath": 'Path to your envrionment'
}
```

However, I think that my approach will set every python project environment to the one you pointed but there should be no problem to override this change on the 'select interpreter' option.