# VS Code Intellisense with modern arcpy syntax

Tags: arcpy, syntax, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know to get VS Code's intellisense to work with modern arcpy syntax?

This post addresses VS Code not recognizing the correct interpreter at all: [VS Code autocomplete for ArcPy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362823/vs-code-autocomplete-for-arcpy)

But that isn't my problem. Using the old syntax, eg arcpy.Buffer_analysis(args) it works fine. Whereas arcpy.analysis.Buffer(args) doesn't.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That syntax isn't new, it's been around for as long as arcpy, it's just being used more now, in the help docs and when you copy from the results window in ArcGIS Pro.

To get VSCode to give you intellisense hints, just import the subpackage you want:

[image]

[image]

Comment: excellent, thank you!

Comment: I use PyWin as my python editor, it has a sort of intelisense if the module is imported in the interactive window, it has no problems with either syntactical expression of the function. That said though I generally keep my python separate to C# or C++ code so I wouldn't see any benefit of editing python in the Visual Studio environment, is there something that I'm missing out on here?

Comment: @MichaelStimson the Q is referring to Visual Studio Code (cross platform, opensource, lightweight code editor with python support), not the Visual Studio IDE. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_what-is-the-difference-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio-ide

Comment: If you're using PyWin, I recommend giving PyCharm or VSCode+Python a run, much more advanced editors/debuggers particularly if you're building projects, using Git for source control, or using multiple virtual/conda environments.